# printing only even columns

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am trying to create a program in python that, once it opens a .csv file, would print (or better, create a new file) with only the even columns.
For example, if my file contains:

A   B   C   D   E

1   2   3   4   5

6   7   8   9   0

The new file would have only:

B   D

2   4

7   9

So far I have this:

```
import csv
ifile=open('Example.csv', 'r')
reader=csv.reader(ifile)
ofile=open('Example2.csv', 'w')
writer=csv.writer(ofile, delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
    writer.writerow(row[1:2]+row[3:4])
    print(row[1:2]+row[3:4])
ifile.close()
ofile.close()
```

But if I have a file containing hundreds of columns, I need a neat way to solve the problem.

Comment: is only your first row getting looked at?

Comment: @Steve did my solution helped you?

Comment: Hi Amit, unfortunately your solution didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your data looks like this(see no new line between rows):

```
A B C D E
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 0
```

You can modify your program as:

```
import csv


ifile=open('Example.csv', 'r')
reader=csv.reader(ifile, delimiter=' ')
ofile=open('Example2.csv', 'w')
writer=csv.writer(ofile, delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
    # Here you check for even
    tmp_row = [col for idx, col in enumerate(row) if (idx + 1) % 2 == 0]
    writer.writerow(tmp_row)
ifile.close()
ofile.close()
```

You loop over each row to get column index and then check for even(odd actually because index starts from 0) columns. Also, you should specify `reader=csv.reader(ifile, delimiter=' ')` delimiter.